# How to deep merge two nested Hashes of Arrays in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, merge

I'm trying to merge two nested array of array of hashes.

```
h1 = {:f => [{:f => [{:name => "a","type"=>"t",:mode=>"n"},{:name => "b","type"=>"t",:mode=>"n"}], :name => "p",:t=>"r"}]}

h2 = {:f => [{:f => [{:name => "a","type"=>"t",:mode=>"n"},{:name => "c","type"=>"t",:mode=>"n"}], :name => "p",:t=>"r"}]}
```

Here's what I'm expecting as output.

```
{:f => [{:f => [{:name => "a","type"=>"t",:mode=>"n"},{:name => "b","type"=>"t",:mode=>"n"},{:name => "c","type"=>"t",:mode=>"n"}], :name => "p",:t=>"r"}]}
```

I've used deep_merge & deep_merge! However that doesn't give me desired outcome. Appreciate any pointers.

Thanks,
Navneet

Comment: `deep_merge`?  Never heard of it.  Ah, from Rails.  You should add a `Rails` or `ActiveSupport` tag, and reference that in your sentence, "I've used deep_merge...".  (Downvote not mine.)

Comment: There is no easy way to do this, as you want to treat your external array differently than the internal one - you want to iterate over the former and sum latter. There won;t be any general solution working for any nesting structure.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comment there will be no general solution for what you want. The code below should work for your nesting structure (and is extremely ugly):

```
{f: [h1[:f].first.deep_merge(h2[:f].first) { |key, old, new| old == new ? new : (Array.wrap(old) + Array.wrap(new)).uniq }]}
```

The question is - why do you need to do this? Most likely there is better way to do what you are trying to achieve by this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I wrote to solve it:

```
    class ::Array
     def mergeFields(second)
      second.each do |sElem|
       match = false
       self.each do |fElem|
        puts "Comparing: #{sElem[:name]} and #{fElem[:name]}"
        if sElem[:name] == fElem[:name]
         if !sElem[:fields].nil? && !fElem[:fields].nil? && sElem[:fields].is_a?(Array) && fElem[:fields].is_a?(Array)
          fElem[:fields].mergeFields(sElem[:fields])
         end  
         match = true
         break
        end
       end
       if match == false
        self << sElem  
       end 
      end
     end
    end

    h1 = {:fields => [{:fields => [{:name => "a","type"=>"t",:mode=>"n"},{:name => "b","type"=>"t",:mode=>"n"}], :name => "p",:t=>"r"},{:name => "e", :t => "s", :m => "n"}]}


    h2 = {:fields => [{:fields => [{:name => "a","type"=>"t",:mode=>"n"},{:name => "c","type"=>"t",:mode=>"n"}], :name => "p",:t=>"r"},{:name => "q", :t => "s", :m => "n"}]}

    h1[:fields].mergeFields(h2[:fields])
```